# Highlight current and up-one-level URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of navlinks. When I'm on a certain page, that navlink should be highlighted. I also want the page up (only) one level to have its navlink highlighted as well, so:

```
All pages: /blogs, blogs/careers, blogs/authors

Page: /blogs/author
Highlight: /blogs/author, /blogs

Page: /blogs/author/Lauren-Stephenson
Highlight: /blogs/author/Lauren-Stephenson, blogs/authors
```

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
import React from 'react';

const navlinks = ["/blogs", "blogs/careers", "blogs/authors"]
const currentPath = "/blogs/authors/Lauren-Stephenson"

export function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
     {navlinks.map((links) => 
       <div style={{color: currentPath.includes(links) ? 'green' : 'white'}}>{links}</div>
     )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

But my code not only highlights `/blogs/Authors/`, it also highlights `/blogs`, which is incorrect, because I only want the page up one level to be highlighted.

How can I do this?

Comment: so do a string equals? startsWith? Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Please update your question with actual code you have tried using actual input values - sort of alludes to some HTML and CSS also?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? What router library are you using? Are you using a framework like React? You've showed what your code does incorrectly, but what's your desired output? In your example, are you hoping that `/blogs/Authors/` gets highlighted as well?

Comment: Probably not a "5.6 Amp 1.0 HP 120-Volt Variable-Speed Fixed Base Corded Palm Router" at least :)

Comment: Welcome, testcoder101. You need to be more clear. You should provide (a) the data you have, (b) the result you are trying to achieve, (c) what you have tried so far. The word "green" has very little to do with your actual question, I suspect.

Comment: @espascarella  : it's been edited with an example

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss It's been edited

Comment: @code its been edited

Comment: @Phrogz its been edited

Comment: So, if I understand correctly you only want to highlight the current link and a link up a level, if any, but not up two or more levels?

Comment: @code yes. thats correct

Answer (score 0):

so maybe adding this condidtion might help you!

```
style={{color: currentPath.includes(links) && currentPath.length!==links.length ? 'green' : 'white'}}
```

it will be sure that it's not the same, if this wasn't the case you can change it from equals to < or > based on your need